# Очередь задач с контролем памяти в Rust

Tags: rust

Я пытаюсь написать программу, которая ищет информацию в файлах по заданным параметрам.
Изначально собираются пути до файлов, создается очередь.
Далее запускаются несколько потоков, которые читают содержимое и осуществляют поиск.

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы количество запущенных одновременно потоков было ограничено не заданным изначально числом, а ресурсами системы, в частности количеством доступной оперативной памяти.

Как бы вы реализовали что-то подобное?

Comment: Использовать более одного потока для работы с жёстким диском — плохая идея, производительность от этого очень сильно упадёт. Или подразумевается работа со сверхбыстрым SSD?

Comment: Работа скорее всего с SSD